# Convert version string to pack_format

Tags: code-golf, string, number

When making a Minecraft data/resource pack, you need to include a `pack.mcmeta` file, which specifies information about it. `pack.mcmeta` contains a description, but it also contains a `pack_format` number, which tells Minecraft which versions this pack is for.

Your task is to take a version string, and output what `pack_format` number matches the string.

Your input must be a string, and you can assume it's either `1.x` or `1.x.y`.

As of when this challenge was posted, the conversion goes like so:

```
1.6.1 - 1.8.9 -> 1
1.9 - 1.10.2 -> 2
1.11 - 1.12.2 -> 3
1.13 - 1.14.4 -> 4
1.15 - 1.16.1 -> 5
1.16.2 - 1.16.5 -> 6
1.17 -> 7
```

These are all the possible inputs, and what they need to be mapped to:

```
1.6.1 -> 1
1.6.2 -> 1
1.6.4 -> 1
1.7.2 -> 1
1.7.4 -> 1
1.7.5 -> 1
1.7.6 -> 1
1.7.7 -> 1
1.7.8 -> 1
1.7.9 -> 1
1.7.10 -> 1
1.8 -> 1
1.8.1 -> 1
1.8.2 -> 1
1.8.3 -> 1
1.8.4 -> 1
1.8.5 -> 1
1.8.6 -> 1
1.8.7 -> 1
1.8.8 -> 1
1.8.9 -> 1
1.9 -> 2
1.9.1 -> 2
1.9.2 -> 2
1.9.3 -> 2
1.9.4 -> 2
1.10 -> 2
1.10.1 -> 2
1.10.2 -> 2
1.11 -> 3
1.11.1 -> 3
1.11.2 -> 3
1.12 -> 3
1.12.1 -> 3
1.12.2 -> 3
1.13.1 -> 4
1.13.2 -> 4
1.14 -> 4
1.14.1 -> 4
1.14.2 -> 4
1.14.3 -> 4
1.14.4 -> 4
1.15 -> 5
1.15.1 -> 5
1.15.2 -> 5
1.16 -> 5
1.16.1 -> 5
1.16.2 -> 6
1.16.3 -> 6
1.16.4 -> 6
1.16.5 -> 6
1.17 -> 7
```

This is code golf, so the shortest answer wins. Good luck!

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22319/92727)

Comment: Are we allowed to assume a trailing zero at the end of major versions (e.g. `1.16.0` instead of `1.16`)?

Answer (score 25):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>43</s>  42 bytes

```javascript
s=>([,x,y]=s.split`.`,x*x+x*3+~~y)/51^x>16
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TdJNToNAFAfwfU8xaZow09KxfKMNuKoXcFlrIHxUDIHKIKFp2hOYuHGp9/A8vYBHQMoU3mzIL2/@897LhFe/8llQJLtynuVh1MROwxwXr@Va3m8cRtkuTUqPenI9rWf1VJudTntyYyjPtauYje@sN8sientPighLMZMILSI/fEjS6HGfBXhBaJk/lkWSbTHhvfD4KRsTGufFyg9eMEOOiw4jhNaoklERMbRBDmJ9Fs1dNCbL9jzIM5anEU3zLfYmh4ru/HCVhdgkxzYzOcS4IkeEOZDjdL3ukfT3@3n@/mq/ErpD0vnnQzoSr@14JI1CTapcJiijC1Wg3tOCqiVWDaAJtIA28BaoLHoP5zasYMMwm2pAHWgATaAFFPoOczuoF/BZnCpQA@o9@apccK31cE/pqlonKlodLEhIqEJC43WdWx2sg4SELib42ldDvnsioxO/ebU62AQJiesPYHJrgnXBxuDu0a1/)

#### How?

Given an input string `1.x.y`, we compute:

$$\left\lfloor\frac{x^2+3x+y}{51}\right\rfloor$$

Because we're using `~~y`, we implicitly assume \$y=0\$ if the input string is just `1.x`.

This gives the correct result for all versions except the last one, which gives \$6\$ instead of \$7\$. This is fixed by XOR'ing with \$1\$ if \$x>16\$.

Comment: I'm curious, how do you get these insanely precise formulae?

Comment: @ophact Trying \$x^2+y\$ was a total guess. I noticed that \$\lfloor (x^2+y)/40\rfloor\$ was already surprisingly good. I then wrote a small script to fine-tune the formula.

Comment: Wow. I guess I'll try some of that.

Answer (score 8):

## Excel, <s>46</s> 44 bytes

*-2 bytes change first item from 6.1 to 0*

```
=MATCH(MID(A1,3,9)*1,{0,9,11,13,15,16.2,17})
```

Since they are all 1.x or 1.x.y, this basically matches everything from the 3rd character on.

Comment: Do you need the trailing `})`?

Comment: I need the `}` for sure. If I leave the `)` off, Excel will add it.  I went ahead and counted it.

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES7), 31 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.slice(2)**2/45+.2|s[3]%1.2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TdJdToNAEAfw955i0tSw29pVlk811Kd6gT7WJiV8VAyByiKJqdzAxBcf9R6epxfwCAhsy@wL@WX2PzuTDc9@5YugSPblPMvDqIm9RngLwUSaBBHhdDrlV6Y1Y/xdrI3Nhc54U0Qvr0kRES0WGmVF5IcPSRqt3rKAXFNW5quySLIdoUzs06Qk48dsTFmcF0s/eCICvAUcRgBrqC6hiARswANxzsJ8AWN6154HeSbyNGJpviPbyaFiez9cZiGxad1mJoeYVLQGIgGe1991D9rf7@fx@6v9anAL2vHnQ4MZkD407zK0ptt2QE0bndlM7wbqo44caZ7pYNVRqxbSRjpIF3mD1K/PHs5dXMHFYS4zkCbSQtpIB6ncO8ztwTvIWZIcaSDNM@WqUtjWeujT@6rRi6nmgxUpCa4kDFk3pflgE6UkTDUh1z4Z8/0TWb1k58l8sI1SEqcfwJY2FJuKrcH9ozv/)

TIO setup is based on Arnauld's answer.

Ignore the `1.` part and treat the input as a floating point number. For example, `1.16.1` becomes `16.1`. This formula (find out by some brute force search) works quite good (48/52 correctness).

$$\left\lfloor\frac{s^2}{45}+0.2\right\rfloor$$

And with some manually fix... It finally works.

So if you are interesting in how it works: I don't know why it work either.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
ṫ3V×⁵>“Ym²Ɱƙʋ‘S‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TdI9asNAEAXgPqdwG3AU74925caXCAhyADfBPkAKg1y5SOnCNiRVcGUwOFiFSScTF7mF9iJraUfaN4XgY@atZlj2bTqbvXtfXw4qv27cspy44vN1Xv240/G2@/9wxfal@Xz9e67Kv3V9@W76g6fJwBVf19UwX1T7av/86L1ITCLahnhoKUHd06JqeTUFDWjBDByDYtQ79jOskGFYlihQgyloQAuy/8a5AbIFzSJKUIG6J61KwrHG8ZwIVRWUcMtoJpaQLKGorskyWkMsoXmC1u6MfLiiNIhOdpbRBmKJ7gEYsmLWzGl0uHR7Bw)

```
ṫ3V×⁵>“Zn³Ɲɱȥ‘S‘   Main Link; take the string as required
ṫ3                 Remove the first two characters
  V                Eval it
   ×⁵              Multiply it by 10
     >“Zn³Ɲɱȥ‘     Compare (>) to each of [89, 109, 130, 149, 161, 169]
              S    Sum
               ‘   Increment
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>94</strike> <strike>60</strike> 57 bytes

```python
lambda s:sum(x<=float(s[2:])for x in(0,9,11,13,15,16.2,17))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdLNjsIgEAfwsz4Ft0KCRD4K1USfYm9uD90Vo6ZqU@hu9@m7tSjDftx@mfkPQwjNlz/ernI4bF6Hurq87Svk1mbhugvut/ajqrHbiXVJDrcW9eh0xSvKOeWS8pxyzQTlhpDh83iqLXppO7uez3q0GYNN5zGZzyrnbOvRAffMNfXJ4wxlZLcsCdrcU/5nXZTjSNP@qS9LVp8757EmFGWLbUb/OXHs2L6x797ux/7vcwfONONosUV8fqcAqicNVE1azYEaaIAFcAXky6djv4ArFLCsYBKogDlQAw0wOTfunSDuCLsCBVAC1ZPhqkEwNjrO8akqJ7HUIjpRkhBJQoa6ChbRCpQkVJoI134Y8tMT5ZPC5MMiWoOSxOMD6GCZWCXOo6dHN98)

This function takes the string `s` and returns the corresponding `pack_format`.

-34 bytes thanks to Command Master (using `lambda` and `sum` instead of a basic loop + a stopping condition)

-3 bytes thanks to tsh (flipping the conditional, changing the list structure, replacing `float` with `eval`)

Comment: [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##XdJLboMwEAbgdTiFd9iSg/ADQ5DgFN2lLNIGFCQCCIxCT08JBo/b3aeZf5iRRf@jH10rlir7XJrb8@t@Q2M6Tk9cNd1N4/HK04Lk2YyqbkAzqlsc0gtljDJBWUSZCjhlMSHL61E3JfoYpjL1TjPK1mg/aUy8Uz/UrcZzMPZNrbGPfHINC4r8c@5TVP1vkLVTzn35rcv72v/T5QVZWKAChs45Yt6bHCgPxlCN3WoEVMAYmAAvQBYetv0ETkhgWRIIoARGQAWMgc537d4N/A2zy5ADBVAeNKcawdhqO8e2qtgUuObWjpwEdxLC1KUxt5YgJyHdhDl7N@S3J4o2mcnd3FqBnMT@Ayhj4Vg6jqy3R49/AQ) with a lambda function and using sum instead of a loop

Comment: `float(s[2:])>=x ` -> `x<=float(s[2:])` save a space.

Comment: `lambda s:7-sum(x>eval(s[2:])for x in(9,11,13,15,16.2,17))`

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>67</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>60</s></sup> 58 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!
Saved <s>4</s> 6 bytes thanks to [tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)!!!
Saved 2 bytes thanks to [rtpax](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85545/rtpax)!!!

```c
y;f(p){p=(~-sscanf(p,"1.%d.%d",&p,&y)*y+p*p+3*p)/51+p/17;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZPLboMwEEX3@QoLiYh3Yt6I0k3Vr2iyQMYkqC2xMFJJo/TTSx1gTNLHqtFEPswdrj3YJvaOkL4/pqXG9BPLtA@bc5LX4tFSsKMWIhRryazlUTeOJjOY6RlMXwXYZCscpee@qlv0mle1pi9OCyR@ZJ83Bmopb/nTFmXoJHxCBysWGsAF8EeIIBPNmQAgBIgAYoAEAK9HmpQYporBOHY8AB8gAAgBIgDpM80AA/gm4JuAbwK@sBS8hmJBUzWGDHZmAk2OUnOl5smcJ3Mwny81f9ZgWYKgLoBR1geyPoRRauGsSS@5X4LALVLO6bDllzNAO0ZJS4txz7GF/hPuH@H9CP@3CG4jvIpoWvJ4SsmekmfaiDWj4aRuukd30yUP4j80efXsQbPloUHapeOqLmgnXlunE94hXr3TQ6nBt9BXU8KQmRSZ5lCto/G6XF0Z4TVem6Fgm0r9MhsXaqm1@m2Wiqz88t9fY40oKTVF5ci@R2qBVL6pRVuthbgle6dZxreT7Xlx7j9J@ZLveG@/fQE)

Uses a variation of [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s formula from his [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225920/9481).

Comment: It's allowed to read from stdin in the default I/O methods, so I think you can just use normal `scanf`.

Comment: @ceilingcat Nice one - thanks! :D

Comment: @ceilingcat completely remove the type (use default int) still (at least) works on TIO

Comment: @tsh Well spotted - thanks! :D

Comment: @CommandMaster When I have some time, I'll check that out - thanks! :D

Comment: [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##pZPLboMwEEX3@QoLiQgCIZg3cumm6lc0WSBjEtSWIoxUaMSvlzrAmKSPVdEgH@aOr21s0@2R0mHoSK5V@rlLbMI5TUvxZSrYUjMRirmuzHWnkyrRqk1luOLt9J2PjWqHQ9IPRdmg17QoNX11XiHx0FNab1DDeMOfDihBZ2EVWFgx0QgOgDdBCJlwyfgAAUAIEAHEANieaFYiGCoC48hyATwAHyAACAGkzzwCNOAbg28MvjH4wlSwDcWC5moMGWwtBJpspeZIzZU5V@ZgPE9q3qLBtARBnQ@trPdlfQCt1IJFk15yvwSBW6j0ZNzyyxlgbcVow7Jpz7GJ/hPOH@H@CO@38G8juIpwnvJ0SumJ0WdWizmj8aTu20dn38YP4h0XefXtwmLztxpplxUXZcZa0c0mM94hXnywt1yDf6Hv5sRGZggyjLFaR9N1uboywmu6NmPBgUj9MhoXaq41@m2Wiaz889@7VbUoyTVF5Wh7j9QMqXxfimU1JuKmXDtLEn6YbftVP3zS/CU98mH7/gU "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @rtpax Very nice - thanks! :D

Comment: With some more UB: `y;f(p){p=(~-sscanf(p,"1.%d.%d",&p,&y)*y+p*p+3*p)/51+p/17;}`

Comment: @tsh Bring on the UB, if it saves bytes we don't care! :D

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 18 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Port of [hyper-neutrino's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225918/58974) so be sure to upvote them too.

```
Ò"Ym¡©"¬mc x<¢*A
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=0iJZbYKVoakirG1jIHg8oipB&footer=W1RnV/opJz1VIih7Z1ZnVLApZ2BwhnNmYWlsYPI0fSkiXbg&input=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) (Includes all test cases)

```
Ò"..."¬mc x<¢*A     :Implicit input of string U
Ò                   :Negate the bitwise NOT of
 "..."              :String containing the characters at codepoints 89, 109, 130, 149, 161 & 169
      ¬             :Split
       m            :Map
        c           :  Codepoint
          x         :Reduce by addition
           <        :After checking each is less than
            ¢       :  Slice the first 2 characters off U
             *A     :  Multiply by 10
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), [69 bytes](https://tio.run/##LZDdasMwDIXv@xSilBKzTtTxXwxeHmM3Y4wNEmgZSUloRyl79tQ@ykW@Ix3pyJBLN/36Zb7@UE/V7qboQcvHyye9d9N8Ggceuj/YKbVvKVU3zf6QEQu0Bg3oQM81NKjlf1Ptvg77PlMpPo@nodrSa0tbxfP3nfpxopSvsabCGrSZAXVYawd6MIANGEF9zFKMBmcaRBs2oAUd6MEAyn45gA/JiGREMiKJ0/qIaZYy1qg1rwJLIFYtlpHOSIdbViy7WngmC2YOkAUnCx5gvZE/Kp0RsSJIhXZ5Ag)

```perl6
[+] Version.new($v) <<>=<<(v1.6,v1.9,v1.11,v1.13,v1.15,v1.16.2,v1.17)
```

Like Perl, Raku has native support for version string comparison. See [Version](https://docs.raku.org/type/Version) for more info.

**Explanation**

- `Version.new($v)` converts from `Str` to `Version` type (it's a shame `v$v` doesn't work)
- `<<>=<<` hyper-operator converts major versions to `Bool`s
- `[+]` counts `True` values

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 93 bytes

```java
s->{var i=Float.valueOf(s.substring(2));return i<9?1:i<11?2:i<13?3:i<15?4:i<16.2?5:i<17?6:7;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZPPcpswEMbP4Sk0nKCtNUH8c4xtbpnJodODj44PiiM8cmUgSDDOePwUPfTSp8uLuBLCZs1lf9/q00rA7p52dLJ//33hh7pqFNprjVvFBS7acqt4VeJvmVO3b4Jv0VZQKdFPykt0cpB@eKlYU9AtQ6tKdKw56QSSBr2Vani5wxhLPzv35qGIVFTp0FX8HR10qcG53iDa7KR/ch6eh5PnduXHiz5lx5plsbjIyfLU0QbxxbOoqMIdFS37VXgSy/ZN9naP@H7WMNU2JeLzpzyY8XkQ5MSEMA9NiPPIhASTPDaQ5skszc6XzHkwxRWTSqIFcgOc4ABNlih4LQ0TwNGNU5BP7/Ix4ARwCngK@Alw8HgTo2UKrjMFx05xCDgCHANOAKeAYf3xCj2RnuypAxPAIeDoxvbqA4K9Woybgz4fWsR3gowCIjQRaArtSjQIMooIIDRFdyb7GlcB9vQfL7Zot18FGUUCEJqGdkkGEUIRQRGPov8rqav7sKgaz/Si4CWb2Y7EshZcee5r6fpmTMxMGctRt6qxXddNDdfP@pm7PqtPqdgBV63CtR4SJUrvuH7coO/I2jUUmNa1@Ozzfr9gst5dGrOPlgrpDRN5G7/jOtj4PsqR@/Xvj4tmJv7Vt9QvYmf/7Jwv/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

```
¦¦T*•BÎΣÚÁÿ•Ƶζв›O>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf9vc2FiaWX//8KmwqZUKuKAokLDjs6jw5rDgcO/4oCixrXOttCy4oC6Tz7//zEuMTYuNQ)

```
¦¦T*•...•Ƶζв›O>  # trimmed program
             O   # sum of all elements of...
            ›    # is...
                 # implicit input...
¦                # excluding the first character...
 ¦               # excluding the first character...
   *             # times...
  T              # 10...
            ›    # greater than...
                 # (implicit) each element of...
           в     # list of base-10 values of base...
         Ƶζ      # 170...
           в     # digits of...
    •...•        # 12728408213639...
              >  # plus 1
                 # implicit output
```

Comment: `•BÎΣÚÁÿ•Ƶζв` -> [`"Ym¡©"Ç`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fKTL3UNOhqYcWHlqpdLj9/39DPUMzPVMA) for -2 (stack exchange removes some characters so I added a link to TIO)

Comment: @CommandMaster Those unprintables aren't in [05AB1E's codepage](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md), so while that lowers the character count by 2, it adds 7 bytes because UTF-8 or similar is necessary to encode those.

Comment: TIO says it's 9 bytes in SBCS 

Comment: @CommandMaster TIO is wrong. It's just too lazy to count characters outside 05AB1E's codepage so it just shows the character count

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 23 bytes

```
L2$"iE₀*`-AViu}`C44+>∑›
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=L2%24%22iE%E2%82%80*%60-AViu%7D%60C44%2B%3E%E2%88%91%E2%80%BA&inputs=1.6.1&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>32</s> 29 bytes

```
ＩＬΦＩ⪪”#｜⊞u⦄,<q'Ｚχ=” ¬›ιＩ✂θ²χ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBCsIwEEWv8slqAmPpVFTEZUE3IoInCCHYgdDaOHj9WKmP/zYfXhxCiVPItd6LjkZ9eBtd0/i0gc6aLZX1eryyGrkWR4hAtpAdZN90kINjODjvGbfJ6FJS@FXKWMOsMdHM6BjSLvo/p1qlkWV188lf) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
     ”...”              Compressed string `0 9 11 13 15 16.2 17`
    ⪪                   Split on spaces
   Ｉ                    Cast to float
  Φ                     Filtered where
             ι          Current value
           ¬›           Is not greater than
               ✂θ²χ¹    Slice of input string
              Ｉ         Cast to float
 Ｌ                      Take the length
Ｉ                       Cast to string
                        Implicitly print
```

Prefixing `0`  to the compressed string or post-incrementing both cost 1 byte. I've stuck with prefixing `0`  as it used to be shorter with the previous method. Edit: Switched to a less-than-or-equals comparison which costs a byte but saves 4 bytes from the compressed string.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 72 bytes

```python
f=lambda p,n=0:float(p[2:])<[9,11,13,15,16.2,17,18][n]and n+1or f(p,n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZJNboMwEIX3OYV3YMVFGX5siEovQllQYpSoqYOCK7WNcnYKhGdatV0VjTQf84Y3tpj23e5PJur7Jj9WL0@7irXC5JttczxV1m@LcFvy@yITRIIiQYkgGYSClKC0LExZmR0zazqdWeMPH66J91Z3tmM58z0KZECeYBOEgPgGChW1VBKABChACsgAtLnRrKQYlcI4DSJADEgAEqAAzmeegATfDL4ZfDP44ii0QfNAczehQsFC0Fx2Wui0yNUiV8O82GnxouFYA6EvQXb9ieuXyE6Ti@a83P8aCG7K4yv91ura6t34o0mw/0T4R0Q/Iv4tku8hv4Tiq3qv62d9nvbx8TVUcT1eYiSKhms0w@ZaodnBsI9D60@7Kxgux7crNjzjNje@5dNLez4Y6zfexV7Z3QO7dFd2mYcUOs@78urx/hM)

Answer (score 0):

## BRASCA 0.5.2, 30 bytes

<sup>The G operator was added on the same day as the challenge was posted, but not specifically for this challenge.</sup>

The program assumes input as `1.x.y` at all times. Ex. `1.16` must be input as `1.16.0`.

The math is from Arnauld's JS answer, go upvote it!

```
C'.iGX$:16S>[7n@]x::*$3*++51S/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVt5d9rGFv@fTzG10wIxYLDjLDzjNk7S1G0T59jueXnHxyUDGkCppFGkUTDdvnrevaMFLQMaxSvnJAZp5t7fXWe74y7EjDu7T13vi2m73BPEX/gtYlMxaxFTME9wbvm1icdtIkybkbiVxZgbPvaoY8Cf6AX@gn9TVoseCI@O2YiO/6jVxhb1fXLoUX9MX@D3fo3AZ2Nj41RAgxbx2NT0galPgAr5TD2TjizmQwPZ0GATMhyajimGw4bPrEmzX5Mv8LMpaciOCZnkJTbu@LLBgJxfZJ9TeNbNPhplHi15PPcYmTNgQA3TmRL2mXmgQPxKfTKeUZAV@X6fZ@xBk6HNDQZ0f6SWz1K435kuM9qmQwwqaPLYnBCHS2tAd2DWMX0qxKLR7CdNUvShwRC7A/llD0TZaJ73@@3eRabThHtk2CJDAkyZE9jMo4I1cqRyjBTM0F5@YAlkmn1zjixbhad5HFnLdKjrMsdocM9ohISbzaQ5A52VSQ5estTqTxSdKDLOiDGHuGAEwQyyYCJnH2qhqhbDuEXRRmcz0ydz07KILzj4AIVvYsbICAz@BxPE5b4pTO7kPG4@My02tDh3fSD61z8ZioyM0SHQYZGUy5G5lyWALYbRm6KXjkOHSsstn0PkWeYYogRsmwijbiG4mxV3813gzwh0HAFHwSU0aZ4kAl1oMAwbSJ9pYeuUtxQtiu/T1D9TK2CET5YRg5wUXPB9xAO/rmWCbiMbNVcLMuJCQKoCzmvFGobtyqQzHR/yY6MbNikXUAsB9sjyXy35EkBReLCrzM45FtyNE2c@0SRks2HmMRF4TsrzipEYNUkBQzZh7ObQlKqAu2nhbwFmN9bYKYQxAooHjwSTz8QwfhiZJP6ZxRc/JQOISbqhSFc0TpVLBYVY871Hqt6jYu@Uz6Wx1/3IBZUBjMnuuiTKhGAoY1Mtd7equEXSo6ZaKd3IhCc4HvtMKbJ8k3eqFJ@4RTOhJb0FSVnMmYqZ2mHDd3m6kavBy8aSRSo0AwsGXElNjhAERwhigT5IIz9uNBNWo8C0jPBhnp9gtpud2OCTIcw7MnOO7EsYGC32KeCCZayDk4N4OIPkw20bR6jiTAEHn9wcAcxaIH1AusWJRKFVe0B6mVbSR4o4B6up5WTNA4sFQXc73whH3Uy/qKOafOyGsWKaRbBpBheVGIB3eDiJkoyymWHVbOJc9rmATjGi8i5xS@wlu6@Xob5RqukzL2Dlth2QnfWcPlQ2R7pZAYQufexYTj7yphquQU4XkLFsQr0pRIIjYPniyuUTTgNhSdNxF2RC9iegcofa7KD4dkz2MWwOarUzDvGEixsI7VEwbZEA8tbE2B5jqAEXamC@mWyPO9jUt/icGHzuEB4INxBRc3977EtgJq6LkOdwKCUeDm0K8@JhZMIQABgitfSKnCzClswkN768qHfM1@8f9HuPTw/Onzg/XFz2@w8f7D7c2trrnW5/iRZsYSojh5iTwiSJKcymbppqOmPF2Y@8AWSytfwd5r8UimS2uy/TZ@pNOt95i6zlEnOnSZ0ryF7k80LUJrNEW@l7hQebRI69@5AaD7Jz2DXpp6uIrJTW0vPrbjEVFNy7p0@up0FuR5/cjga5XX1yuxrkHumTe6RBbk@f3J4Gucf65B5rkHuiT@6JBrmn@uSeapB7pk/umQY5q4Ib64TFrxXo6XgeqxAXOsZ9VSEwdALNqBAZOuZ9WcGXdWJjVsFddLz5pyr@ouMwv1QiqEPxr40@2XzJxh7D6YIu8fgRTgTbOhn7H2Rz5FyBzZYOGw/ZyOHuRO7vqvjQ5QisnshKMDqNcBli4rJDbiY3Ri1CAaXaQiskNJu14oAtBQhHe5g@zahXKnj9Q32tY2R3d5VzYq3JdV4KuflVMp3Z6l001xHKzKi2cJFV1MgbiotbF5d2PLVlvhL7FvrBc8O4YQdQuewW1fDTNuI7DUZ48CDuAGRbB@RDBPkmsITpWos7APlQB@R2mFgEm4L3GOZn01ctNG8e7Pa2DtpvpUq5EVj8DjB@qwPxd4T46tLlzqpEfcNW1zK7LwPok3cVhEXmeKTYmcDCL/rqA4MGbTZVSfrQFHMTVrgVstK/CPrt8dm1Yv5XR13fyXz49uUd2PM7HXx/I77jkzuA97cOvCHCe38n@H4HfArvO1Uu4gvAKQJ35dY7X25nP187VUgfJQABDfWMlFwO9bmMdLg8l1ziUxo9YbLHCHrSHKr5HFbgoyVPC/lEW/orNmUyHOK9/1LCfSRsBHh6KrfwQRQ@WcPhazMPvUrLAur/ZFEvT@B0gceHcrqo4vb0GjoUpLFRGpt/zqof4yMkomQZnod9lTFibJKEBr43Cb6couVxXLTxWY6vqs618bkl@iOOLPXx1X5h88ARuis4Z7mC67bCrmvWcNo2uh47vSux0z3Sw3pfuKI/fC@TZVjFFdVLdNu9nSe6fpeUfDVgnZnfV2hqAPgmGeOWR62lSVuxlxEdxuqwfIAs/Tl1paHFnGOxm@0T7lw5md94xh9pyHcibcpFPEiJmcfY7co4vnFFjK@iMuV5TkGPp6jHMXdw3HQSZYK7hIT92/cTjDFfoEhb@IdqRdg0L8ZqB4hqCZBNvd75yE1HsnOay0SWbHxhVcPqpDfGNAfJJJX6Ukd6Ue/yHb0qykHwGup4rVSHPCX2YZKkXvhufuh1dnY7j/Y@kHqHmOQ1GRyQHtnZJY/2lB0M4GvrWBl4YvUGFoA0FqGeL1tkgYpLSnA7U48H7miRUV@LWNQeGZT82Sd/omSSZTMulrq8uDPbSBmQOsi2mswKX4t0IBVw2aw05mk6gBk5AMz7BQEipoljfjT4NdqqA5KM5lrRGJ0pi8kob7XQACXsfDAgj55Glc74e39A9p6s7pfZcgYW5xIJVnPI7gC6XO6jtNzL2shQA42tW5O7mxX72VdLDZBr5WJfyvWPCUQ8o3zNtta5C7Tfp2nrrKx0ZnUFLgFy@c1pnypJOrrzUFnIFabzakcpEKGGzkDzW4RzuhJnOtAvm8tEkfGiWpkbZKvdrltMxabQ0faxhqNxudcma3TwRsDz0xdHR1Hla5nXLWtRCuXoK@tRcqIU69iVp1H4kU0a41n2HLDZgrA2BvW6hqWPV4qqEwR3L20SfFWEdrJCRxn0/ho4bdwKYr5dLeZ9Na7CsEuBFfH8gjvC4xb50eLzcoXso0J@Zb4PCyl600dgqL59Wilx9dSUmI6qq9abHaAuXoN55LWG21HHwf1Vx0Ce6X0KwK1vQRGDwb3VRP1/ddDEIRNzxpz7sLeA@sLZ5Rj/u78O9AM60BnzbBOXorXrSYp4C5BdmkJnbrmJACAfGrI8nFrkY2C7JYldah312i3VR7EGpRTRR0T0M6DA2dwcJtZ@lSKXbAFVObefE254TbUau3aW3ZYGu3Nk91@se27LouliLX5R3eGc9xuc9K5dYGVWSu3eRYmFVkmVCJW@P1BaTa2U9iInLQzJNyXrwY2KquNJL9aXdeXuZeqVip1p0gxvckqatezKJby3JKVwPSZ3ffzkCjNek43q4Yq3KNTF8eqLE5tneOXJFDA1nJD5jDmwxOfA2JNRJUywKbCdwOrdKCmQr1Zwl73alKA5RtayiEQeLCj29FYn80IVXgQuV6qy@UaeocUXefMXeLVSILscM1eQX9hixCHxYLGV5wWuyN2HK2bzqOMr@QfSNhoyJ87mKbdZeAF6zhxB5h53pi08CuBzMA4BTjwLN5xKb7w6OTk@6RNV99zhe9ghueLfgXRtUzEEcPlTmJQI4UWQo8hxoysttaoLh2XbTAiAjylWGGsP@q@wH0oHa2chCowY@mqMxcUqLVuzrSCuDtAlbVokqyQX6bNIbo3YlUUuF7e6qCvFxM@XXqe309n5Pw)

### Explanation

The second number will be called X, the third number will be called Y.

```
C                               - Set implicit output to number mode
   i                            - Turn "0-9" from char into the numbers 0-9
 '. G                           - Split stack by "."
     X                          - Remove the first number, it's not needed.
      $                         - Put X on top of the stack
       :16S>[7n@]x              - If it's more than 16, the version is 1.17.0, so print 7 and terminate.
                                - Calculate the final number:
                  ::*           -   (X**2
                     $3*+       -        + X*3
                         +      -              + Y)
                          51S/  -                  /51
<implicit>                      - Output the number
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 66 bytes

```python
lambda i:sum([float(i[2:])>x+8.2 for x in [.7,2,4,6.2,7.9,8.3]])+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHbCoMwDADQX8ljgiFgHd5g@5GuDx2jGNC2aAX9@npOvsuSYlfD@1tXv/3@HnQ@zg1tWJMvqNbMjj5XM4qBkHa4QCNYGdjwi3sxPMjEo3TOUdPWvGssGFBjPgsSUX0A)

Explanation:

- Our input is `i`. Remove the `1.` at the start with `i[2:]`.
- Convert the rest to a number with `float`.
- For each `x` in the list, check if this is greater than `x+8.2`.

  - Why 8.2? Well, all of the finishing versions (1.8.9, 1.10.2, etc.) are greater than 8, thus saving some bytes.
  - In addition, since two of them end with .2, I can subtract that as well, saving 2 more bytes.
- Since `True` and `False` are treated as `1` and `0` by the arithmetic operators, we can use `sum` to count the number of `True`s in the list.
- This is now off by one, so we add 1.